# jquery datapicker reduce table width

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to reduce the widch of the datepicker table at my site http://ecentriconline.com/surferbeachfront/.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline style definition:

`<div class="datepick-inline" style="width: 282px;">
</div>`

which should be something like

`<div class="datepick-inline" style="width: 225px;">
</div>`

then change traditional.css line 83 to

`.datepick-header {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px;
}`

Then you'll want to play around with your margins and padding to make it sit a bit more nicely.